# driver for Ralink USB RT2870 --> 148f:7601

Tags: debian, network-interface, realtek, usb-device

I bought the Ralink USB Network Interface device listed below

```
$lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp.
```

And I've looked at many threads which all point to the same chipset driver : mt7601u

So I went on GitHub: https://github.com/kuba-moo/mt7601u

Used the custom made driver, which worked fine for a couple of days before I started getting kernel crashes during boot (DO NOT USE THIS DRIVER!!)

So I went back and downloaded the vendor's driver (http://www.mediatek.com/en/downloads1/downloads/mt7601u-usb/)

But anyhow I can't compile. "$make" just crashes probably because i use Linux version 3.16... and at least 3.19 is needed.

```
$uname -r
3.16.0-4-amd64
```

I use Debian and latest stable release is the one I currently have and would like to keep it that way. What is plan B? I have the "firmware-ralink" package installed.

Don't really know what to do next. Maybe I should buy another USB Network Interface? If so please leave suggestions for easy installation with Debian.

I would like to mention that all of this problem is caused by the fact I have a buggy Network Interface in my computer (BEWARE OF REALTEK CHIPSETS!!)

```
$lspci -vnn | grep "Network"
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]
```

***** EDIT *****

Thanks for the answer GAD3R,

I've verified that everything is installed properly. Then I made sure to upgrade everything.

```
$sudo apt-get update
$sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I've appended the modifications to the config.mk file

```
# Support Wpa_Supplicant
HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT=y
# Support Native WpaSupplicant for Network Manger
HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y
```

Still getting an error when compiling:

```
$ sudo make && make install
make -C tools
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/tools'
/home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/tools/bin2h
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/build SUBDIRS=/home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64'
Makefile:10: *** mixed implicit and normal rules: deprecated syntax
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64'
  CC [M]  /home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.o
In file included from /home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/include/rtmp_os.h:42:0,
                 from /home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/include/rt_config.h:72,
                 from /home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:28:
/home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘duplicate_pkt’:
/home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:477:18: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘memmove’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
   NdisMoveMemory(skb->tail, pHeader802_3, HdrLen);
                  ^
/home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/include/os/rt_linux.h:450:61: note: in definition of macro ‘NdisMoveMemory’
 #define NdisMoveMemory(Destination, Source, Length) memmove(Destination, Source, Length)
                                                             ^
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/arch/x86/include/asm/string.h:4:0,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/include/linux/string.h:17,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/include/linux/bitmap.h:8,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/include/linux/cpumask.h:11,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/arch/x86/include/asm/cpumask.h:4,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/arch/x86/include/asm/msr.h:10,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:20,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:23,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/include/linux/thread_info.h:54,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/include/linux/preempt.h:18,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/include/os/rt_linux.h:40,
                 from /home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/include/rtmp_os.h:42,
                 from /home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/include/rt_config.h:72,
                 from /home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:28:
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/arch/x86/include/asm/string_64.h:58:7: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘sk_buff_data_t’
 void *memmove(void *dest, const void *src, size_t count);
       ^
In file included from /home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/include/rtmp_os.h:42:0,
                 from /home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/include/rt_config.h:72,
                 from /home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:28:
/home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:479:18: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘memmove’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
   NdisMoveMemory(skb->tail, pData, DataSize);
                  ^
/home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/include/os/rt_linux.h:450:61: note: in definition of macro ‘NdisMoveMemory’
 #define NdisMoveMemory(Destination, Source, Length) memmove(Destination, Source, Length)
                                                             ^
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/arch/x86/include/asm/string.h:4:0,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/include/linux/string.h:17,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/include/linux/bitmap.h:8,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/include/linux/cpumask.h:11,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/arch/x86/include/asm/cpumask.h:4,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/arch/x86/include/asm/msr.h:10,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:20,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:23,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/include/linux/thread_info.h:54,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/include/linux/preempt.h:18,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/include/linux/seqlock.h:35,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/include/linux/time.h:5,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/include/os/rt_linux.h:40,
                 from /home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/include/rtmp_os.h:42,
                 from /home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/include/rt_config.h:72,
                 from /home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:28:
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/arch/x86/include/asm/string_64.h:58:7: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘sk_buff_data_t’
 void *memmove(void *dest, const void *src, size_t count);
       ^
/home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘ClonePacket’:
/home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:629:23: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
      pClonedPkt->tail = pClonedPkt->data + pClonedPkt->len;
                       ^
/home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘update_os_packet_info’:
/home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:651:15: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
  pOSPkt->tail = pOSPkt->data + pOSPkt->len;
               ^
/home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘wlan_802_11_to_802_3_packet’:
/home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:672:15: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
  pOSPkt->tail = pOSPkt->data + pOSPkt->len;
               ^
/home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘send_monitor_packets’:
/home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:945:9: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
         DBGPRINT(RT_DEBUG_ERROR, ("%s : Size is too large! (%d)\n", __FUNCTION__, pRxBlk->DataSize + sizeof(wlan_ng_prism2_header)));
         ^
/home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘RtmpOSFSInfoChange’:
/home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:1228:20: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int’ from type ‘kuid_t’
   pOSFSInfo->fsuid = current_fsuid();
                    ^
/home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:1229:20: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int’ from type ‘kgid_t’
   pOSFSInfo->fsgid = current_fsgid();  
                    ^
/home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘RtmpOSNetDevDetach’:
/home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:1694:38: warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type
  struct net_device_ops *pNetDevOps = pNetDev->netdev_ops;
                                      ^
/home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘RtmpOSNetDevAttach’:
/home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:1731:38: warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type
  struct net_device_ops *pNetDevOps = pNetDev->netdev_ops;
                                      ^
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/scripts/Makefile.build:262: recipe for target '/home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.o' failed
make[4]: *** [/home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.o] Error 1
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-common/Makefile:1352: recipe for target '_module_/home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux' failed
make[3]: *** [_module_/home/sugar/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1/os/linux] Error 2
Makefile:181: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
make[2]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64'
Makefile:243: recipe for target 'LINUX' failed
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
sugar@sugarraysam:~/downloads/2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1$
```

I can't find a working driver.

The "official Ralink source" that I find all over the web is: http://www.ralinktech.com/. Which is just ads...

Found a Ralink driver from MediaTek (parent company) --> http://mediatek.com/en/downloads1/downloads/mt7612u/. But still getting an error when compiling.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Buying another device is probably a good plan. People don't always realise that their time has value, and messing around with a buggy device isn't the best way to spend it. If you are planning to use a device on a Linux system, do your research before buying. Linux hardware support has improved a great deal in recent years, but is still not guaranteed. Always prefer hardware with free drivers contained in the kernel. Custom/third-party drivers are relatively likely to cause problems.

Comment: Having said that, if you want help, you need to give more details. E.g. "But anyhow I can't compile. "$make" just crashes probably because i use Linux version 3.16... and at least 3.19 is needed." Give all output from make, including error messages, please. Also, why do you think it needs 3.19? If some documentation says so, please state so clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Install dependencies:

```
apt-get install build-essential fakeroot dpkg-dev
apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Download `driver 2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1.tar.bz2` from [here](http://distfiles.lesslinux.org/)

unzip and load directory

```
tar -jxvf 2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1.tar.bz2
cd 2010_0709_RT2870_Linux_STA_v2.4.0.1
```

Edit config.mk
 `nano os/linux/config.mk`

```
# Support Wpa_Supplicant
HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT=y
# Support Native WpaSupplicant for Network Manger
HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y
```

compile

```
make
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

http://gentoo-en.vfose.ru/wiki/Ralink_RT2870 is helpful. Specifically, note that kernel support for the device appears to already be included in the kernel, in the form of the `rt2800usb` driver. See also https://wiki.debian.org/rt2800usb

That page mentions the firmware `rt2870.bin`. `apt-file` returns two hits for this:

```
apt-file search rt2870.bin
firmware-misc-nonfree: /lib/firmware/rt2870.bin
firmware-ralink: /lib/firmware/rt2870.bin
```

`firmware-ralink` is for use with jessie. `firmware-misc-nonfree` is only in unstable.

Comment: Doesn't work. This device variant (USB ID) is not among those supported by the mainline kernel. See https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/rt2800usb